# Constructive interference

Tags: interference

When two waves (having the same wavelength) are inphase and interfere in a constructive interference why just the amplitude of the final wave doubles and not the wavelength??

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia has the answer to this: [Wave propagation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interference_(wave_propagation))

> When the two waves overlap, the net displacement at a particular point
>   is the sum of the displacements of the individual waves.

The net displacement in this article represents the amplitude in your question.